# LockerService and HTMLElement type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

When I create a simple HTML Element,

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

I am unable to set the `type` attribute.

```
div.setAttribute('type', 'whatever');
```

Will LockerService someday support that?

Comment: No official, but it would support these except some actionable attributes like `onclick` , `onchange`

Comment: What error does the locker throw ?

Comment: No error is thrown by Locker. It says it's not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: If you can screenshot exact error its not hard to trace it back here https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js . The docs show this must be supported but we can dig in

Comment: The exact error is `WARNING: SecureElement: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } does not allow getting/setting the type attribute, ignoring!`.

I know why it's not working, LockerService code is not that huge, but they don't accept any PRs so I cannot fix it myself.

Comment: You should be able to use the data api to set 'data-type' (or data-anything). I'm guessing you are using the type attribute for some later processing, rather than rendering anyway - so this could be a good solution.

Comment: I could, but this would be a big framework change and would also break our existing customers. LockerService should not restrict the usage of DOM manipulation like that.

Answer (score 2):

`type` isn't a standard attribute on HTMLDivElement. LockerService will ignore these non-standard attribute names, with some exceptions. Anything with a dash in the name, for example, is allowed to accommodate data-* and 3rd party attributes like ng-*.

https://git.soma.salesforce.com/aura/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js#L436